# Migrating from FME Server 2008 (with Spatial Direct) to FME Server 2011?

Tags: fme-flow

I am about to migrate a web app from it's old architecture to new.  Part of this is migrating the old FME Server 2008 (using a Spatial Direct service) instance to FME Server 2011.

I understand it is quite different; has anyone got any experience of moving to 2011 and can offer some advice?

Comment: FME Server 2012 is a short month away - http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-server/download/ - Note the differences between 32bit and 64bit installs (not all formats are in 64bit due to format vendors not Safe's issue).

Comment: How is your existing FME Server 2008 setup? Tomcat with security etc?

Comment: Yes, using LDAP with certificate and spatial direct.  We have a custom app in java that takes a SOAP request and pouts the query through to a workbench FME

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big question for you (or anyone in this position) is ***are you actually using workspaces or mapping files?***

SpatialDirect started out as a Mapping File only platform, so I won't assume you are even using workspaces. If not, then you could migrate mapping files (I believe) but you will want to schedule some time asap to investigate updating them to workspaces.

I'm not sure what database was in use in SD2008, but 2011 now defaults to Postgres I believe for the job management, etc, so there shouldn't be too much of a problem.

The best thing to do is check out the FME Server Administration Guide. It has a section on upgrading. You can find it on [FMEpedia](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Documentation_del/FME-Server-Administration-Guide) - look in the top-right for the link to the doc.

And if you do have problems, don't hesitate to contact the support team via http://fme.ly/support

Comment: We've banged out customised Java code using SpatialDirect, so I am assuming a rewrite, to be honest.  But I'll follow the guidelines as to see how to replace the SpatialDirect element.

Answer (score 1):

Download your workbench with FME Desktop 2008 (Download from FME Server) and publish them in FME Server 2011 or 2012 (Publish to FME Server). Probability, your FME Database could be migrating in FME Database 2011. Have you Oracle, SQL Server ?

[image: Menu]

Comment: Oracle.  I believe the FME is propriety?

Comment: You have the SQL Script in Installation/Database/Oracle for the creation of FME user and the creation of tables. And you have page 25 of FME SERVER ADMINISTRATOR'S GUIDE, a chapter provides information for upgrading to newer versions of FME Server on Microsoft. Good luck !